# Oscilating function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-sequences

I can't solve this problem from the [4clojure](https://www.4clojure.com) site and the errors are not helping much:

```
;;Write an oscillating iterate: a function that takes an initial value and a
;;variable number of functions. It should return a lazy sequence of the functions
;;applied to the value in order, restarting from the first function after it hits the end.

(fn osc [value & funs]
  (loop [value value
         funs (cycle funs)]
    (cons value (lazy-seq
                 (recur ((first funs) value) (drop 1 funs))))))
```

This version of the function shows this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mismatched argument count to recur,
expected: 0 args, got: 2, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)
```

Why is `recur` expecting `0` arguments, however I tried tried this other function:

```
(fn osc [value & funs]
  (let [value value
         funs (cycle funs)]
    (cons value (lazy-seq
                 (osc ((first funs) value) (drop 1 funs))))))
```

But it yiels this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

The only place I can think of where the error is after the `lazy-seq` function it seems to be ok syntactically.

Both functions fail on this test

```
(= (take 3 (__ 3.14 int double)) [3.14 3 3.0])
```

Comment: The second version is missing just one word to be correct: `apply`. Just find the right place to put it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first attempt doesn't work as the lazy-seq macro calls the body you give it when needed, from a zero-arity fn. So even though your code is in the tail position, it's in the tail position of another function. Gotta love macros. I recommend running (source lazy-seq) to grok it personally.

```
(defn osc-seq [val fns]
  (cons val (lazy-seq (osc-seq ((first fns) val) (rest fns)))))

(defn osc [val & fns]
  (osc-seq val (cycle fns)))
```

Your second attempt has problems due to repeatedly calling cycle and so (first fns) isn't a fn the second time - it's a seq.

Answer (score 2):

- Your first example goes wrong because `recur` is inside a `cons` -
  not in tail position *(wrong - see edit below)*. The error message is misleading.
- The second goes wrong because you apply `cycle` to your `funs` on
  every iteration.

I don't want to answer the question for you, so ...

Consider that if you could call your second function like this:

```
(osc v (cycle funs))
```

... you wouldn't call `cycle` inside it. So construct a function like that, make it local to your apparent function, and call it appropriately.

---

@pete23 is right. In your first example, the `lazy-seq`, not the `cons`, is first in line to spoil tail position for the `recur`.

The *macro* `lazy-seq` wraps its *form* argument as a parameterless function, in this case presenting the translator with

```
(fn [] (recur ((first funs) value) (drop 1 funs)))
```

... in which, as the error message says, the `recur` is supplying 2 arguments when 0 are expected. As this fooled me, and may fool others, I'll leave the edit trail intact.